# Web service Bin folder

Tags: .net, web-services

I created webservice which contain Add function as 'webmethod'

when we want to deploy webservice we need to give web.config,app_data,app_code,.asmx file and Bin file in IIS right .But i am not able to see Bin folder in
solution .Can any one tell me the reason why Bin folder is not coming

Comment: Which is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: visual studio 2005,,framework 2.o

Comment: But iam not finding Dll files responsible for webservice though i added bin folder from "right click the project then in the 'Add ASP.Net folder'" in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VS 2005 or 2008 then Bin won't be initially shown in Solution Explorer.

You have to right click the project then in the '***Add ASP.Net folder***' menu item you can choose '***Bin***'.

Comment: But iam not finding Dll files responsible for webservice though i added bin folder from "right click the project then in the 'Add ASP.Net folder'" in this way

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to deploy it I would right click over the web site and click 'Publish Web Site'

It will prompt you for a location.  Then take the items from that directory.